# Handling errors in browser script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

There is a simple code excerpt:

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId,
    range: "TOP!A:B"
}).then(result => {
       doSomething()
})
```

How to detect and handle errors if they occur?

Errors like 503,403 etc. that are appear in response data:

```
{error:...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, how about this modification?

#### Modified script:

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId,
    range: "TOP!A:B"
}).then(result => {
       doSomething()
}, (error) => { // Added
    if (error.status == 403) { // You can also use switch().
      console.log('Status code is 403. Message: %s', error.result.error.message);
    } else if (error.status == 503) {
      console.log('Status code is 503. Message: %s', error.result.error.message);
    }
})
```

#### Reference:

- [Google API Client Libraries JavaScript Samples](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: **Wonderful!** Thank you very much!

Comment: @Max S Thank you for your response.